# How to delete the commas at the previous line before specific string by PYTHON

Tags: python

I'm dealing with a tough question.
I need to delete some commas at the end of the line, which is previous some specific strings.

Such as:

```
define{
   varA,
   varB,
   varC
}
```

The specific string is varC, and I want to delete varC and the comma(,) after varB at the same time.

The modified text is

```
define{
   varA,
   varB
}
```

I must deal with many code files so I need a script to do it, but that's tough for me.

Comment: can this question be understood as "removing the last `varX`"?

Comment: Actually, yes. It's simple to remove last varX, but it's hard for me to delete the comma before varX in previous line. I only know how to read files by readline() so I can only deal with file line by line. How to deal with the previous line?

Comment: if you `var` is variable then `var[:-6:]+'}'`

Comment: What is ```define```?

Comment: This is removing the entire last line,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regex that looks for the `define` blocks, separating them in 3 groups:

- the first one starting with `define{ ...` and taking everything afterwards non-greedily, including newlines (so we'll need the `re.DOTALL` flag to allow `.` to match newlines)
- the second one is the part we want to remove: a comma, some space, some word
- the third one is the final spaces and closing `}`

We just have to use `re.sub` to replace the matches by the first and third groups only:

```
data = """ 
some code
some more code
define{
   varA,
   varB,
   varC
}
some code
define{
   varD,
   varE
}
end of code
"""

import re

define_re = re.compile(r'(define{.*?)(,\s+\w+)(\s+})', re.DOTALL)
out = define_re.sub(r'\1\3', data)

print(out)
```

Output:

```
some code
some more code
define{
   varA,
   varB
}
some code
define{
   varD
}
end of code
```